# Регистрация на Asterisk из за NAT

Tags: udp, asterisk, nat, sip

как прописать настройки endpoint чтобы я мог регистироваться на астере из за NAT? Вижу что астер отправляет назад пакет с ответом 401, но на клиенте говорит что таймаут. Получаеться что ответный пакет не приходит клиенту, на какой стороне это надо настраивать?

---

[image: настройка клиента]

---

Настройка астериска:

```
[6003]
type = endpoint
transport = transport-nat-udp
context = test
disallow = all
allow = ulaw
aors = 6003
auth = auth6003
direct_media=no


[6003]
type = aor
max_contacts = 100

[auth6003]
type=auth
auth_type=userpass
password=пароль
username=6003
```

---

дамп:

```
<--- Received SIP request (820 bytes) from UDP:188.163.0.11:48630 --->
REGISTER sip:адрес сервера:5060;transport=UDP SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 188.163.0.11:48630;branch=z9hG4bKcfbdb686c114d7faca8cbfe99b64572a
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 188.163.0.11:48630;branch=z9hG4bK-524287-1---3745eee367349747;rport
From: <sip:6003@адрес сервера:5060;transport=UDP>;tag=7d71c609
To: <sip:6003@адрес сервера:5060;transport=UDP>
Call-ID: Akc93-Lm8I_qgh4mG8qsqA..
CSeq: 1 REGISTER
Contact: <sip:6003@188.163.0.11:48630;transport=UDP>
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, BYE, NOTIFY, REFER, MESSAGE, OPTIONS, INFO, SUBSCRIBE
Max-forwards: 69
Expires: 70
User-agent: Z 3.9.32144 r32121
allow-events: presence
allow-events: kpml
Content-Length: 0


<--- Transmitting SIP response (604 bytes) to UDP:188.163.0.11:48630 --->
SIP/2.0 401 Unauthorized
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 188.163.0.11:48630;rport=48630;received=188.163.0.11;branch=z9hG4bKcfbdb686c114d7faca8cbfe99b64572a
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 188.163.0.11:48630;rport;branch=z9hG4bK-   524287-1---3745eee367349747
Call-ID: Akc93-Lm8I_qgh4mG8qsqA..
From: <sip:6003@адрес сервера>;tag=7d71c609
To: <sip:6003@адрес сервера>;tag=z9hG4bKcfbdb686c114d7faca8cbfe99b64572a
CSeq: 1 REGISTER
WWW-Authenticate: Digest  realm="asterisk",nonce="1469703075/8c0a49002abe1ee30e9aa1cefc70ba4b",opaque="4d344eeb1ef4ef24",algorithm=md5,qop="auth"
Server: Asterisk PBX 13.8.0
Content-Length:  0
```

Comment: Смотреть нужно настройки NAT. Провайдер один?

Comment: Нет. Предполагается что регистрация к астериску будет приходить с разных точек. Настройки NAT на чем именно? Вот как у меня прописан транспорт на астериске `[transport-nat-udp]
type=transport
protocol=udp
bind=0.0.0.0
local_net=10.24.2.0/24
local_net=127.0.0.1/32
external_media_address=внешний IP
external_signaling_address=внешний IP
`

Comment: Если 188.163.0.11:48630 реальный адрес endpoint, возможно пакеты блокируются оператором или шлюзом на стороне получателя.

Comment: Проблем может быть вагон. Астер за натом? Sip alg в роутере включен? Для extension'ов клиентов правильно прописаны настройки comedia, rport,nat?

Comment: @gecube. На роутере Sip alg  включен. Меня как раз и интересует что нужно прописать на для  endpoint чтоб они работали з NAT.

Comment: @StuxForce это скорее всего адрес последнего перед астером  роутера